# sql transaction not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

SQL transaction not working:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION AddEmployees
   INSERT INTO Employees
      VALUES(N'595002', N'John Meah', N'20000212', 32.25),
      (N'928375', N'Chuck Stansil', N'20080628'),
      (N'792764', N'Orlando Perez', N'20000616', 12.95);
   COMMIT TRANSACTION AddEmployees;
GO
```

Comment: hey @bluefeet this transcation not working

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Comment: "hey @bluefeet this transcation not working"  You do know that stackoverflow is not your instant messaging client, right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is you are using wrong syntax. In SQL-Server 2005 you cannot use commas `,` between the `values` statements. You have to specify each `INSERT INTO....VALUES...` statement. And then in your second `INSERT` you do not have the correct number of parameters:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION AddEmployees
   INSERT INTO Employees
      VALUES(N'595002', N'John Meah', N'20000212', 32.25)

    INSERT INTO Employees
      VALUES(N'928375', N'Chuck Stansil', N'20080628', null)

    INSERT INTO Employees
      VALUES(N'792764', N'Orlando Perez', N'20000616', 12.95)
   COMMIT TRANSACTION AddEmployees;
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

you're missing parameter at the row, use this row:

```
(N'928375', N'Chuck Stansil', N'20080628', null),
```

It's not about the transaction, it's because the number of columns for each row in a table value constructor must be the same.

If your table doesn't allows null, then pass the relevant parameter, of DEFAULT.

Comment: +1 http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d07fe/1

Comment: @Tamir they are using sql-server 2005  as well and they cannot use commas between the values statements

Answer (score 1):

make default value for fourth database field  so the statement may get execute.